# Sublime Text 2: leave goto windows on focus lost

Tags: sublime-text-2, focus

How to set it not to close goto window: For example, I open it to install package, then Alt+Tab to browser. When I choose what to install and go back to Sublime - there is no more goto window so I need to reopen it.

If there an way to not to close it when Sublime window loose focus?